# Counting blank text box as 0 value While Text Boxes are Empty

Tags: vb.net

I am have written the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim pos As Integer = 0
Dim neg As Integer = 0
Dim zer As Integer = 0
Dim TextBoxes() As String = {Val(TextBox1.Text), Val(TextBox2.Text),
                              Val(TextBox3.Text), Val(TextBox4.Text),
                              Val(TextBox5.Text), Val(TextBox6.Text),
                              Val(TextBox7.Text), Val(TextBox8.Text),
                              Val(TextBox9.Text), Val(TextBox10.Text)}
For i = 0 To 9
    If TextBoxes(i) > 0 Then
        pos += 1
    End If
    If TextBoxes(i) < 0 Then
        neg += 1
    End If
    If TextBoxes(i) = 0 Then
        zer += 1
    End If
Next i
Label4.Text = (pos)
Label5.Text = (neg)
Label6.Text = (zer)
```

When the program executes and I put some values into the text boxes, the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfp4L.jpg).  The first text box contains `1` which is positive and the other one contains `-1` which is negative.  It's working well.

The problem occurs here: the program is counting the empty boxes as `0` and displaying `8` in the total number of zeros.  All of the other 8 text boxes were left blank.  How can I Fix the issue so that it doesn't count the empty text boxes as `0`.

For reference, here is my related, previous problem which has already been solved: [Finding String of Substring in VB without using library function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908084/finding-string-of-substring-in-vb-without-using-library-function)

Comment: Yes you could fix your problem. Start to set OPTION STRICT ON in the VS options.

Comment: @Rob I will be careful in future.

Comment: @Steve the became difficult after USING STRICT OPTION ON

Comment: what is your problem. Empty textbox should not count as 0?

Comment: @SATSON  Yes. but my problem is Solved.....

Comment: I solved the my previous problem by following the procedure of Paul. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15910866/2262815). I want to get the solution of my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `Val` function to get the value in each text box.  `Val` returns `0` if the given text is empty or non-numeric.  If you want to check that, you should just store the original strings in the array and then check the value in the loop, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim pos As Integer = 0
Dim neg As Integer = 0
Dim zer As Integer = 0
Dim TextBoxes() As String = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,
                              TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text,
                              TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text,
                              TextBox7.Text, TextBox8.Text,
                              TextBox9.Text, TextBox10.Text}
For i = 0 To 9
    If TextBoxes(i) <> String.Empty Then
        If Val(TextBoxes(i)) > 0 Then
            pos += 1
        End If
        If Val(TextBoxes(i)) < 0 Then
            neg += 1
        End If
        If Val(TextBoxes(i)) = 0 Then
            zer += 1
        End If
    End If
Next i
Label4.Text = pos.ToString()
Label5.Text = neg.ToString()
Label6.Text = zer.ToString()
```

However, the `Val` function is mainly just provided for backwards compatibility with VB6.  It will work, but I would recommend using `Integer.TryParse` instead.  Note that I also added `ToString` to the last three lines.  As others have mentioned, it would behoove you to turn `Option Strict On`.

Comment: I solved the my previous problem by following the procedure of Paul. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15910866/2262815). I want to Solve my own code. Hope you will do it.